# What is the LaTeX command for this font style:

Tags: fonts, packages

What is the LaTeX command for this font style shown in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: The image uses math and text with more than one font style. For which element you want to know the font style?

Comment: I got this style by using a package (\usepackage{....}), but I forgot what was the package "...", if you can tell the name of that package....

Comment: If you have the PDF file, then you can check the fonts used in there, e.g. `pdffonts document.pdf` or the menu option of Acrobat Reader.

Comment: You could try browsing through the [serif section of the Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffonts.html) to see if you find a match (or you may remember the package name when you see it).

Comment: \mathcal for calligraphic font