# Can this font be implemented in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, typography

The following image shows a small excerpt from an article in *American Mathematical Monthly* from 1968:

[image]

What font is being used here, and can it be reasonably easily implemented in LaTeX?

Comment: You can see http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/.

Comment: There is another post here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344439/what-is-the-latex-command-for-this-font-style. There is a similar picture.

Comment: @Sebastiano Do the fonts really look similar to you?

Comment: Looking the `x` it would appear that it is very similar, but is not equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font seems Baskerville, a clone of which is available also for math. Not really identical, though (for example the letter lambda).

Some clues are the characteristic “C”, “T” and “7”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[baskervaldx]{newtxmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}

Each element $x\ne0$ of a given quantity structure $S$ is on
a biray $[x]=\{ax:a\in R\}$ (Sect.~7), consisting of the
elements of the same type as $x$; the positive part $[x]^+$
of $[x]$ is a ray. Thus $[\mathrm{in}]=[\mathrm{ft}]=[-100\,\mathrm{ft}]$,
called the ``dimension'' of length. Considering each $[x]$ as an
element of a new system given us in a natural manner a vector space~$[S]$
(Sect.~8) written multiplicatively; this is the space of possible
``physical dimensions.'' If $[x_1],\dots,[x_n]$ forms a base for $[S]$,
then each element of $S$ can be written in the form
\begin{equation}
x=ax_1^{\alpha_1}\dotsm x_n^{\alpha_n};
\end{equation}
the representation is unique if $x\ne0$ (see~Sect.~9).

An isomorphism $\phi$ of $S$ onto itself is a ``similarity'' if it
preserves type: $[\phi(x)]=[x]$ (and preserves positiveness). With a
base as above, the general similarity is defined by $\phi(x_i)=\lambda_ix_i$
for some positive numbers $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ (Sect.~11).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed quite close.  It seems also that this clone is a bit bolder than the old AMM font.  Is there a version that is less bold?

Comment: @joshphysics Keep in mind that the printing technology used at the time was quite different from today's.

Comment: Yeah that did occur to me, and perhaps that would essentially completely account for the difference.  The only other real difference I can see which can't be attributed to printing is that the old version's inter-word spacing (and perhaps some inter-character spacings in general) is slightly different.  Can that be adjusted manually?

Comment: @joshphysics To tell you the truth, I've always found the printing of the Monthly rather sloppy (look at the uneven space for [ft]). The math spacing is old fashioned (if not wrong). The interword spacing is, in my opinion, too wide.

Comment: Good points.  I'll attempt to suppress my nostalgia.

Comment: @joshphysics To help with that, you may want to read Knuth's "Mathematical Typography" paper (his Gibbs lecture of 1978) especially the section (p. 343) where (discussing _Transactions of the AMS_) he says "At this point I regretfully stopped submitting papers to the American Mathematical Society, since the finished product was just too painful for me to look at." :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Ha!  I'll definitely read it.